# Is it possible to read data from the text browser of QT GUI

Tags: qt, datareader, qtextbrowser

i'm trying to make a chat application in QT . Is it possible to read data from the text browser of QT GUI(which shows conversations) so that i can maintain a chat history...?plz help..Thank You

Comment: What kind of control is the text-browser? QLineEdit?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I think he means QTextBrowser!?

Comment: Hint: [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextbrowser.html) and parent [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextedit.html). See toHtml(). And next time use manual.

Comment: @all :Thank you...Sorry I didn't see that..

Comment: I'd rather write the messages to the history as you receive them, that also gives you better control over the format you store it in. (single messages instead of one big html blob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QTextBrowser`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtextbrowser.html) inherits [`QTextEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtextedit.html), which works on a [`QTextDocument`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtextdocument.html). The QTextDocument can be converted to (and saved as) HTML using [`QTextDocument::toHtml()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtextdocument.html#toHtml):

```
QTextDocument *doc = ui->textBrowser->document();
QString html = doc->toHtml();
```

---

I advise you to append to a log file every time a new message comes in / goes out, so update the QTextBrowser and the file "in parallel", and **not** saving the entire chat history everytime a new message appears.

To do so, open the log file and manually write the open `<html>` and `<body>` tags without closing them. Then append the chat log entries on the still opened file. On application exit (object destruction of the chat window or whatever), close the `</body>` and `</html>` tags and afterwards the file itself. This will result in  a much better performance than saving the whole file for every change of the QTextBrowser widget.

Answer (score 0):

with something like that:

```
QString myQString = <textBrowserObject>.toPlainText();
```